# How to match any character existing between a pattern and a semicolon

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to get anything existing between `sample_id=` and `;` in a vector like this:

```
sample_id=10221108;gender=male
tissue_id=23;sample_id=321108;gender=male
treatment=no;tissue_id=98;sample_id=22
```

My desired output would be:

```
10221108
321108
22
```

How can I get this?

I've been trying several things like this, but I don't find the way to do it correctly:

```
clinical_data$sample_id<-c(sapply(myvector, function(x) sub("subject_id=.;", "\\1", x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` with a capture group to isolate that which you are trying to match:

```
out <- sub("^.*\\bsample_id=(\\d+).*$", "\\1", x)
out

[1] "10221108" "321108"   "22"
```

**Data:**

```
x <- c("sample_id=10221108;gender=male",
       "tissue_id=23;sample_id=321108;gender=male",
       "treatment=no;tissue_id=98;sample_id=22")
```

Note that the actual output above is character, not numeric.  But, you may easily convert using `as.numeric` if you need to do that.

**Edit:**

If you are unsure that the sample IDs would always be just digits, here is another version you may use to capture any content following `sample_id`:

```
out <- sub("^.*\\bsample_id=([^;]+).*$", "\\1", x)
out
```

Comment: Could I use `(\\.+)` instead of  `(\\d+)` ? Because, in some cases, sample_id is composed by words, not digits.

Comment: No.  You mean to use `(.+)`.  Yes, you can do that.  I assumed you only ever had numbers, since all your sample data seems to imply this.

Comment: You're right, Im gonna change the example. 

I am trying this command `sub("^.*\\bsubject_id=(.+).*$", "\\1", x)` but it returns everything after `sample_id` instead of stopping in the `;`. I've tried also `sub("^.*\\bsubject_id=(.+).*;", "\\1", x)` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Please _don't_ change your question like this after others have already answered. Just use `sub("^.*\\bsample_id=([^;]+).*$", "\\1", x)` if you want the content after `sample_id` but before the next semicolon (if there is a next semicolon).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the str_extract method which utilizes the Stringr package.
If your data is separated by line, you can do:

```
str_extract("(?<=\\bsample_id=)([:digit:]+)") #this tells the extraction to target anything that is proceeded by a sample_id= and is a series of digits, the + captures all of the digits
```

This would extract just the numbers per line, if your data is all collected like that, it becomes a tad more difficult because you will have to tell the extraction to continue even if it has extracted something. The code would look something like this:

```
str_extract_all("((?<=sample_id=)\\d+)")
```

This code will extract all of the numbers you're looking for and the output will be a list. From there you can manipulate the list as you see fit.